# TFS Release, running PowerShell, cannot create DtlDownloads

Tags: tfs, ms-release-management

I am trying to get some automatic deployments up and running using TFS 15 (on-premise). I have a powershell script on the deployment target to call.

The deployments starts fine by downloading the artifact. But when the agent runs the script it wants to create a folder `C:\Windows\DtlDownloads` (thats not part of my script but part of preparing things for TFS I guess). That fails:

```
##[debug]System.AggregateException: Failed to install 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployer20597940-38b2-4ba8-9a4d-fcc894308730' from service executable path VisualStudioRemoteDeployer.exe . Consult the logs below:
Access to the path 'DtlDownloads' is denied.
CategoryInfo :PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\DtlDownloads:String) [New-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
FullyQualifiedErrorId :CreateDirectoryUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

The user used to logon is a server-local user named `deploy` who is also a local administrator on that machine. I also checked the *effective access* for that user on the windows folder and it should be able to create directories.

Something similar happens with the copy step. Robocopy signals two errors:

```
2017/03/16 08:57:21 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Getting File System Type of Destination \\server.domain.com\c$\abc\def\ 
Access is denied.
```

and

```
2017/03/16 08:57:21 ERROR 5 (0x00000005) Creating Destination Directory \\server.domain.com\c$\abc\def\ 
Access is denied.
```

The second is a bit unexpected as the folder `def` already exists but I guess it is a follow up because getting the type failed beforehand.

The user itself must have been recognized because I get different errors when using invalid credentials. I have enabled WinRM using `Enable-PSRemoting` and `ConfigureWinRM.ps1` from [WinRM-Http-Https-Without-Makecert](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-rm-documentation/tree/master/WinRM/WinRM-Http-Https-Without-Makecert).

What could still restrict the permissions?

---

Update: Using a domain user instead of a local one of that server solves the issue. But I do not understand why. Can someone explain or even provide information how to make it work with a local user?

Comment: Are you using the **Deploy: PowerShell on Target Machines** task in your release definition?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT Yes.

Comment: Can you share the entire logs?

Answer (score 1):

> The username of either a domain or a local administrative account on
>   the target host(s).
>
> - Formats such as **username, domain\username, machine-name\username,** and    **.\username** are supported.
> - UPN formats such as **username@domain.com** and built-in system accounts    such as **NT Authority\System** are not supported.
>
> [Source Link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines)

Both the domain account and local admin should be work. Please double check your format and give a try with another format.

Comment: I tried **.\deploy** and **machine-name\deploy** - both without success. I even tried UPN format which as stated above did also not work.

Comment: @ZoolWay Could you give a try with manually run the powershell script on deployment target machine when using the deploy account?

Comment: @ZoolWay Also try to turn off  the firewall on the on deployment target machine or  opening  the firewall restriction related to WinRM such as use `netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="WinRM-HTTP" dir=in localport=5985 protocol=TCP action=allow` The firewall may be the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

One problem could be if that you have the agent as a service, that service has not the proper privileges, like being on Network Account. Try to change that to the user account which has administrative privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Running "winrm quickconfig" fixed this problem for me

```
winrm quickconfig
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrm/installation-and-configuration-for-windows-remote-management